# Drop 1st row of every outer index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has two levels of indices. The first level consists of the strings in the list `names`, and the second levels consists of `datetime` objects. I am trying to remove the first row at every outer index

For example:

```
>>> print(df)

                   val1   val2
name   date
Tom    2018-01-01   2.3    5.4
       2018-01-02   3.6    8.2
Jerry  2018-02-18   5.7    1.3
       2018-02-19   7.2    3.8
```

---

```
names = ['Tom', 'Jerry']

for name in names:
    df.loc[name].drop(<row 0 of this name>, inplace=True)
```

---

```
>>> print(df)

                   val1   val2
name   date
Tom    2018-01-02   3.6    8.2
Jerry  2018-02-19   7.2    3.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for first indices:

```
names = ['Tom', 'Jerry']
idx = [df.xs(name, drop_level=False).index[0] for name in names]
df = df.drop(idx)
print (df)
                  val1  val2
name  date                  
Tom   2018-01-02   3.6   8.2
Jerry 2018-02-19   7.2   3.8
```

For drop all first rows by first level use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) + [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) for mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()]
print (df)
                  val1  val2
name  date                  
Tom   2018-01-02   3.6   8.2
Jerry 2018-02-19   7.2   3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

First flatten the index.

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

Then drop duplicates as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Tom', '2018-01-01', 2.3, 5.4],
                   ['Tom', '2018-01-02', 3.6, 8.2],
                   ['Jerry', '2018-02-18', 5.7, 1.3],
                   ['Jerry', '2018-02-19', 7.2, 3.8]],
                  columns=['name', 'date', 'val1', 'val2'])

df = df.drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')
```

Comment: @jezarael's solution is better if you want to "remove first row" rather than "keep last row".

Answer (score 0):

I would like using `reset_index`

```
df.reset_index().groupby(['name']).last().set_index('date',append=True)
Out[1015]: 
                  val1  val2
name  date                  
Jerry 2018-02-19   7.2   3.8
Tom   2018-01-02   3.6   8.2
```

Or if more than 2 within one subgruop

```
df.reset_index('name').groupby(['name']).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:])
Out[1018]: 
                   name  val1  val2
name  date                         
Jerry 2018-02-19  Jerry   7.2   3.8
Tom   2018-01-02    Tom   3.6   8.2
```